# how to optimize multiple Array.find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have JSON: (It has way too many rows, but would be too long to paste whole json)

```
"data": {
  "rows": [
      {
          "row_no": "130",
          "sum_begin_period": "3234122.29",
          "sum_end_period": "3099063"
      },
      {
          "row_no": "150",
          "sum_begin_period": "1252394",
          "sum_end_period": "986382"
      },
      {
          "row_no": "160",
          "sum_begin_period": "1321400.28",
          "sum_end_period": "1321400"
      },
      {
          "row_no": "210",
          "sum_begin_period": "3367691.4",
          "sum_end_period": "1282444"
      },
      {
          "row_no": "220",
          "sum_begin_period": "2320199.07",
          "sum_end_period": "265000"
      },
      {
          "row_no": "260",
          "sum_begin_period": "1047492.33",
          "sum_end_period": "1017444"
      },
      {
          "row_no": "610",
          "sum_begin_period": "825495.3",
          "sum_end_period": "960385"
      }
  ]
}
```

I need to do some math operations for which I need values from multiple rows. How can I do that elegantly?

What I have tried till now:

with Array.find():

```
let ccScore;
  for(const row of finance_report){

    const satr_390_1 = finance_report.find((row) => row.row_no === "390");
    const satr_190_1 = finance_report.find((row) => row.row_no === "190");
    const satr_211_1 = finance_report.find((row) => row.row_no === "211");
    const satr_600_1 = finance_report.find((row) => row.row_no === "600");

    if (satr_600_1== 0) return 1;

    ccScore = (satr_390_1 - satr_190_1- satr_211_1) / satr_600_1;

    if (ccScore < 0.5) return 1;
    else if (ccScore >= 0.5 && ccScore < 2) return 3;
    else if (ccScore >= 2) return 5;
  }
```

Disadvantage of above is Array.find is being repeated way too many times.

 with Array.maps(): (searching with IF statement inside a callback of .map())

```
 let accounting_factor;

  accounting_report.map((row) => {
    let summ = 0;
    if (row.row_no === "480") summ += parseInt(row.sum_end_period);
    if (row.row_no === "490") summ += parseInt(row.sum_end_period);

    if (row.row_no === "130") {
      accounting_factor =
        parseInt(row.sum_end_period) > parseInt(summ) ? false : true;
    }
  });
```

Disadvantage of above is IF being repeated. 
 Is there a more elegant approach which does not force me to repeat my code and enables me to extract objects(from "rows" array) with certain rows.row_no and then do operation?

 P.S. If Array.reduce() can solve the issue, I would appreciate an example of it

Comment: You can definitely move the finance_report.find()'s outside of the for-loop

Comment: You also use return's inside the for-loop? Why?

Comment: @Tacos I would prefer not to pollute outer scope. Anyway, how would it make the code better/more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restructure the data as follows

```
let rows = {}

original.data.rows.forEach(row => rows[row.row_no] = row)

// USAGE
rows[ROW_NUM].sum_end_period
```

You can try this out, I believe it'll be faster because a key value tuple is an indexed object and the program won't have to iterate over each element in the array.

Comment: This is good and I voted up, but you should filter first to avoid a huge new structure

Comment: @TiagoCoelho True, but I feel the approach without filter() is better in my case. Because I have to perform multiple math operations and each of them requires different rows. With filter(), I need to filter data for each individual math operation. Thanks anyway)

Answer (score 3):

Map your data to rows using a reduction function.

```js
const mapped = data.rows.reduce((a,v)=>{a[v.row_no]=v;return a},{})
```

Now your rows are indexed by row_no

```
mapped['100']
```

You can also use destructuring in your reduction. (thanks jsNOOb)

```js
const mapped = data.rows.reduce((a,v)=>({...a, [v.row_no]: v}),{})
```

Comment: `const mapped = data.rows.reduce((a,v)=>({...a, [v.row_no]: v}),{})` - wondering if this will work too. Uses destructuring `a` in liue of the `return`.

Comment: I will add as option to solution. thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is actually wht i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Would [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) do the job?

```js
const rowNrsINeed = [220, 130, 800];
const filtered = retrieveData().data.rows.filter(row => 
  rowNrsINeed.find(no => no === +row.row_no));

filtered.forEach( r => 
  console.log(`row: ${r.row_no}; sum_begin_period: ${r.sum_end_period}`) )

for (let row of filtered) {
  // ... do stuff with each found row
}

function retrieveData() {
  return {
    "data": {
      "rows": [{
          "row_no": "130",
          "sum_begin_period": "3234122.29",
          "sum_end_period": "3099063"
        },
        {
          "row_no": "150",
          "sum_begin_period": "1252394",
          "sum_end_period": "986382"
        },
        {
          "row_no": "160",
          "sum_begin_period": "1321400.28",
          "sum_end_period": "1321400"
        },
        {
          "row_no": "210",
          "sum_begin_period": "3367691.4",
          "sum_end_period": "1282444"
        },
        {
          "row_no": "220",
          "sum_begin_period": "2320199.07",
          "sum_end_period": "265000"
        },
        {
          "row_no": "260",
          "sum_begin_period": "1047492.33",
          "sum_end_period": "1017444"
        },
        {
          "row_no": "610",
          "sum_begin_period": "825495.3",
          "sum_end_period": "960385"
        }
      ]
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: `includes` would be more appropriate than `find` in your filter (but a `Set` and `has` would be better).

Answer (score 0):

### Use filter, includes and reduce

```
const wantedRowIds = [390,190,211,600];
const wantedRows = finance_report.filter(row => wantedRowIds.includes(+row.row_no));

const rowsById = wantedRows.reduce((acc,row) => ({...acc, [row.row_no]:row}),{});
```

Then use them like  `ccScore = rowsById[390] - rowsById[190] - rowsById[211] / rowsById[600];`

Comment: changed `find` to `filter` as I think you intended. But rather than using `includes` you should use a `Set` and `.has()`. `const wantedRowIds = new Set([390, 190, 211, 600]); ... wantedRowIds.has(+row.row_no)`

Comment: thank you for the correction. Why should I use Set?

Comment: on a short array like this it's negligible, but on larger arrays Set.has() offers significantly more efficient lookups than Array.includes.